# Get-AzSubscription not working but Get-AzureRMSubscription is working

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm

When I am trying to execute some Powershell commands like Get-AzSubscription, it is not working but I get output when I use Get-AzureRMSubscription. Same is the case for other commands as well like Get-AzVM, New-AzSnapshotConfig, New-AzSnapshot.

The Azure RM versions installed on my machine are:-

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name AzureRM.Resources

ModuleType Version    Name
Script     6.7.3      AzureRM.Resources
Script     5.5.2      AzureRM.Resources
```

Why is it so ? When I tried on Azure portal cloudshell, it worked just fine with Get-AzSubscription, Get-AzVM, New-AzSnapshotConfig, New-AzSnapshot, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Got to understand. Either AzureRM or Az can be loaded at a time. Uninstalled AzureRM module and installed Az and all Az commands are working now.

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber
```

Now:-

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Az.Resources

ModuleType Version    Name
---------- -------    ----  
Script     2.0.1      Az.Resources
```